# How to open file in nano in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, system, nano

So I am writing a C program that is more of a shell and I have come to the point where I need to create a command to open a file in nano. I actually have this working pretty nicely and it is all working. Except that I am getting a Sh 1. Permission Denied when I open a file.

```
char filename[4080];
printf("Enter the file you wish to edit: ");
scanf("%s", filename);
char thething[4080];
sprintf(thething, "/usr/local/script/send_it.pl %s",
filename);
system(filename);`
```

When I run it this is what happens

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/JacoShell $ sudo ./shell

JacoShell: /home/pi/JacoShell $nano
Enter the file you wish to edit: /home/pi/JacoShell/test.txt
sh: 1: /home/pi/JacoShell/test.txt: Permission denied

JacoShell: /home/pi/JacoShell $
```

./shell is chmoded appropriately so I don't know what the problem is

Comment: You're trying to execute `/home/pi/JacoShell/test.txt`, not `nano`.

Comment: @lxg, no I'm not. Have you ever heard of JacoShell? That's because I am writing it. It prompts you for the file and passes that file name to nano is shows in the code

Comment: So `system` is a function you've written?

Comment: ...but `system()` is defined to invoke `sh`, not JacoShell (or bash, or ksh, or anything else that isn't `sh`).

Comment: @JacobMisirian I think you need to read more about the [`system`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) function.

Comment: system() is a part of the C standard library used ro execute linux executables. I actually have it executing nano by itself and working just fin. This is just executing it with arguments.

Comment: @JacobMisirian, incorrect -- `system()` doesn't invoke executables directly; it does so through a shell. If you want to invoke executables _directly_, read the manual for the execve() family of calls -- this is what _real_ shells do.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to pass `thething` to `system()`, not `filename`. As written, your code does not use the results of that `sprintf()`.

Before you do that, though, you may want to consider what happens if your filename contains a space or other special characters…

Comment: A space? That's not scary. If your file is `/tmp/$(rm -rf /)/hello`, that's more interesting. :)

Comment: ...that said, encouraging someone who's writing a shell to use `system()` at all is a bit unfortunate -- given as `system()` itself invokes a shell.

Comment: sh: 1: /usr/local/script/send_it.pl: not found

Comment: Oh, I see, you're copying code from [ancient forum threads](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/52075-need-pass-parameters-system.html). That script was part of the original question. It doesn't exist on your system. You'll need to use an appropriate command.